# Is there a way I can catch hold of my host element from input change event using angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using angular2 md-input. I want to find my host element on change event.

If I use `(ngModelChange)="inputValue($event)`, $event passes me only the value in my .ts file.

If I use `(change)="inputValue($event.target)`, $event.target passes the input element in my .ts file.

Is there a way to get hold of my `<md-input>` DOM element in my .ts file on change event?

Answer (score 2):

Add a tempalte variable and pass it as parameter (1st or 2nd doesn't matter, it's just an example):

```
<md-input #myInput (ngModelChange)="inputValue($event, myInput)">
```

Comment: Great!! This is exactly what I was looking for.